# Knockout.js add item to foreach from ajax call

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a view model like this

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.blogUpdate = ko.observableArray();
}

var vm = new AppViewModel();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('/Blog/GetUpdates?id=89', function (response) {
        vm.blogUpdate = ko.observableArray(response);
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    });
});

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: blogUpdate">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: title"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: body"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a button that opens a dynamically created modal / dialog with form inputs.  On submit, it posts back by ajax and on the success function I try to push the newly created JSON.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            global: false,
            url: '/Blog/NewUpdate',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                vm.blogUpdate.push(response)
            }
        });
```

If I access the array I can see it there but the interface does not update.  The examples I see use a `data-bind="click: updateFunc"` on the button.  But my button just opens up a modal that lets you enter text and ajax posts back.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/wvwh2x3n/1/

I think you need to parse the response before you push to the observable array. Would probably look someething like...

```
success: function (response) {
    var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
    vm.blogUpdate.push(new BlogPost{ parsed.prop1, parsed.prop2 })
}

var BlogPost = function(prop1, prop2) {
    var self = this;
    self.prop1 = ko.observable(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(prop1));
    self.prop2 = ko.observable(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(prop2));
}
```

You should use data-bind="modal: xyz" as seen in the fiddle. Just don't forget all the bindings setup work etc.

In regards to the markup from new items... If you have an observableArray setup that you foreach, then it should just be a case of pushing to it. If you have some code we can see ill try my best to help.

i love knockout :D

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: Users" class="list-group hover">
      <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.EditUser">Show modal</a> |
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-bind="modal: UserBeingEdited" class="fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
  <form>
    <div class="modal-header">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
      <h3>User Details</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="NameInput">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="NameInput" placeholder="User's name" data-bind="value: UserBeingEdited() && UserBeingEdited().Name, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="AgeInput">Age</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AgeInput" placeholder="User's age" data-bind="value: UserBeingEdited() && UserBeingEdited().Age, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">
      </div>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/**** These styles are here to override the styles in 'bootstrap-modal-bs3patch.css' ****/

$screen-sm-min = 768px; //<== Standard Bootstrap width

.modal {
  left: 25%;
  width: 50% !important;

  @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    left: 50%;
    width: 500px;
  }

  @media (max-width: $screen-sm-min) {
    left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

JS

```
ko.bindingHandlers['modal'] = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
    var $element = $(element);
    $element.addClass('hide modal');

    if (allBindings.modalOptions && allBindings.modalOptions.beforeClose) {
      $element.on('hide', function() {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        return allBindings.modalOptions.beforeClose(value);
      });
    }
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    if (value) {
      $(element).removeClass('hide').modal('show');
    } else {
      $(element).modal('hide');
    }
  }
};

/* ViewModel for the individual records in our collection. */
var User = function(name, age) {
  var self = this;
  self.Name = ko.observable(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(name));
  self.Age = ko.observable(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(age));
}

/* The page's main ViewModel. */
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.Users = ko.observableArray();

  // The instance of the user currently being edited.
  self.UserBeingEdited = ko.observable();

  // Used to keep a reference back to the original user record being edited
  self.OriginalUserInstance = ko.observable();


  self.EditUser = function(user) {
    // Keep a copy of the original instance so we don't modify it's values in the editor
    self.OriginalUserInstance(user);

    // Copy the user data into a new instance for editing
    self.UserBeingEdited(new User(user.Name, user.Age));

  }
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();

// Populate the ViewModel with some dummy data
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  var letter = String.fromCharCode(i + 64);
  var userName = 'User ' + letter;
  var userAge = i * 2;
  viewModel.Users.push(new User(userName, userAge));
}

// Let Knockout do its magic!
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Actually it was working.  For some reason, I was expecting it to show up at the top but it showed up at the bottom instead.  Need to use `unshift` instead of `push`.